# How to append angular ui uib-template to body but still have the reference to the directives' controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I've got a directive and I have to append a tooltip to one of its elemenets. But due to existing HTML/CSS code I have to append it to the body instead of this element. But I still need some properties from this directive to render them in the tooltip. How can I do that?

Comment: use fiddle or codepen to explain your problem , it will be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this was a really dumb question of mine. Turns out that angular js automatically passes all the nessecary data to the template as if it was in the same scope.